# EXTJS4 Xtemplate

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

As a bit of a begginer in the EXTJS world I was hoping for a bit of advise as I am a little stuck here:

I am pulling information from a store using Xtemplate.

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">',
            '<p>{data.address}</p>',
            '<p>{data.ip}</p>',
            '</br>',
            '</tpl>'
        );
```

This displays a string for {data.address} as /domain/hub/servername.

I am trying to understand how I might beable to just display the "servername" section.

Reading the docs I see there you can use a function inside so I tried and failed with:

```
'<p>{[RegExp(".*/(.*)", data.address)]}</p>',
```

I am probably quite far off the mark there, like I say I am struggling with this one. Any advise welcome! thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combination of `inline code` and `Template member functions` like this:

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '<p>{[this.getServerName(values.data.address)]}</p>',
    '<p>{data.ip}</p>',
    '</br>',
    '</tpl>',
    {
        getServerName: function(fulladdress) {
            return fulladdress.replace(/.*\//g, '');
        }
    }
);
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/eUhf9/1/).

Comment: your a super hero indeed!

I dont understand where you get (fulladdress) from?

Comment: @CarlDraper, fulladress = values.data.address. You send `data.address` into `getServerName` function as an argument (and xtemplate renders the return of this function instead of `data.address`).

Comment: In ExtJS4.2 I needed to use `values.address` rather than `values.data.address`